# Swift create tableview with custom cell within UIAlertviewcontroller

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uialertcontroller

I am trying to create `Tableview` with `custom cell`display within `UIAlertviewcontroller` using `swift 4`. Please provide some idea or sample link here.

Comment: not possible , you have to do it custom

Comment: okey thank you. is there any samples? @Sh_Khan

Answer (score 0):

Native `UIAlertviewcontroller` does not support embedding custom views. You can create custom alert controller or use one of many open source libraries and pods.